# Getting elements with the wrong class, using bs4 and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all `tr` elements with the `class="odd"`. But when I use the `find_all` command to find `tr` elements with the `class = odd`, it retrieves all the `tr` elements.

In my code you can see, that I have used the `find_all` command to find `tr` with `class = odd`, in the second picture is a screenshot showing the source code from Oddsportal, where there is both `tr` elements with `class "odd"` and `"odd deactive"` class. In the third picture is my output from my code, where you can see the first tag is a `tr` tag with the class `"odd deactivate"`. 
[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]
[image: picture 3]

Comment: It's best to copy and paste your code here rather than provide screenshots of it -- the screenshots make it impossible to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you have bs4 version installed **4.7.1** or above you can use css selector `select()` instead of `find_all()`.

To get only `odd` class value you need to exclude the class `deactivate`

Try below code which is excluding the `deactivate` class and only keep `odd` class

```
listelement=sovs.select('tr.odd:not(.deactivate)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XPath `contains` query to get `tr` elements with class 'odd', even when they have 'odd deactivate' instead of just odd. The BS4 query is not working because the class name is meant to be an exact match in your query. Here's how you can work around that:

```
tr_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(@class, 'odd')]")
```

This will get your `tr` elements with class `odd` and `odd deactivate`.

You can also use the `*=` query in a CSS selector for BS4 to accomplish the same thing, detailed in their [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) on CSS selectors:

```
tr_elements = sovs.select('tr[class*="odd"]')
```

Hope this helps you a bit.